# CFStringCompare Overload

Tags: swift, cfstring

I am attempting to use CFStringCompare to compare strings, but I keep getting a `Could not find an overload for ==  that accepts the supplied arguments.` More specifically, the bit of code looks like:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!)
{
let mediaType = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaType) as String


if CFStringCompare(mediaType as NSString!,  kUTTypeMovie, compareOptions: 0) == CFComparisonResult.CompareEqualTo

{

   var moviePath : NSString = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL).path

   if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)
   {

      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, nil, nil, nil)

   }

}
else ...
```

I'm sure I'm just screwing up the syntax, however I've tried making mediaType an Optional String and unwrapping it:

```
let mediaType = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaType) as String?
```

and still `could not find overload for ==`.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I presume that `CFStringCompare` compares CFString, but you're sending it `NSString?` and `NSString`.

Comment: Why not simply `if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie { ... }` ?

Comment: @nhgrif if I didn't cast it as a NSString from a String, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `CFStringCompare()`  method not correct (note: `compareOptions` is a parameter not a name) , Try like this :

```
   let compareResult = CFStringCompare(mediaType as NSString!, kUTTypeMovie, CFStringCompareFlags.CompareCaseInsensitive)

   if compareResult == CFComparisonResult.CompareEqualTo {

              println("Equal")

          }
    else {
              println("Not Equal")

         }
```

You can provide different flags as u need `CFStringCompareFlags(0)` in your case.

If you are not using compare flags it can be easily done with :

```
if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
//Equal
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I'm translating from Objective-C to Swift, so I never would have caught that without your keen eye. Thanks!